# Hasty forkjoin alternative rxjs for observable chaining?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have 5 different API calls to make, and they all are chained right now in forkJoin. 
My new requirement is the subscribe should fire anytime any new observable solves.

Is there any operator or any other trick in rxjs where I can keep the chaining but, it should fire each time any observable solves?

```
forkJoin(
        this.myService.api1(),
        this.myService.api2(),
        this.myService.api3(),
        this.myService.api4(),
        this.myService.api5()
    )
        .subscribe(
            ([r1,r2,r3,r4,r5]) => { ... do something })
```

Comment: Do you mean you need something like [CombineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) ?

Comment: What do you specifically mean by "chaining". Does order matter? Do the calls depend on each other in any way?

Comment: I tried combineLatest, and its logging just once when I tried to log in the subscribe method

Comment: No, the order don't matter. They are not dependent. I can do individual subscribe for each method, but that just adds extra lines of code.

Comment: You could try [merge](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/merge).

Comment: Sorry, the order of the variables matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` to execute your observables simultaneously like forkJoin but emit their values immediately. To keep track of the order add the index of the observable to its output with `map`. Use `scan` to keep track of previous values, insert current values at the right position in the array and emit the accumulated data.

```ts
export function forkJoinEarly(...sources: Observable<any>[]): Observable<any[]> {
  return merge(...sources.map((obs, index) => obs.pipe(
    // optional: only emit last value like forkJoin
    last(), 
    // add the index of the observable to the output
    map(value => ({ index, value })) 
  ))).pipe(
    // use scan to keep track of previous values and insert current values
    scan((acc, curr) => (acc[curr.index] = curr.value, acc), Array(sources.length).fill(undefined))
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-gwch8m

Answer (score 1):

You can use `combineLatest` to emit the latest value from each source observable. It won't emit until each source observable emits at least once, so you can use `startWith` to provide a starting value:

```js
combineLatest(
        this.myService.api1().pipe(startWith(null)),
        this.myService.api2().pipe(startWith(null)),
        this.myService.api3().pipe(startWith(null)),
        this.myService.api4().pipe(startWith(null)),
        this.myService.api5().pipe(startWith(null))
    )
        .subscribe(
            ([r1,r2,r3,r4,r5]) => { ... do something })
```

The initial output will be `[null, null, null, null, null]`. When each observable emits, it will replace the corresponding `null` value in the array.

If you want to ignore the initial emission, you can use `skip(1)`.

```js
const sourceOne = of('Hello').pipe(delay(1000));
const sourceTwo = of('World!').pipe(delay(2000));
const sourceThree = of('Goodbye').pipe(delay(3000));
const sourceFour = of('World!').pipe(delay(4000));

//wait until all observables have emitted a value then emit all as an array
const example = combineLatest(
  sourceOne.pipe(startWith(null)),
  sourceTwo.pipe(startWith(null)),
  sourceThree.pipe(startWith(null)),
  sourceFour.pipe(startWith(null))
)
.pipe(skip(1));

//output:
//["Hello", null, null, null]
//["Hello", "World!", null null]
//["Hello", "World!", "Goodbye", null]
//["Hello", "World!", "Goodbye", "World!"]
//Complete
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val), null, () => console.log('Complete'));
```

And here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-wuena5) to try it out.